# a good diet for a person with high mind activity?

Tags: weight-loss, diet

im 24 and 180cm height and about 95kg weight. i am a programmer and as you know its a job that needs to think and its a mind activity.

i have a good diet and if i follow the orders of the diet it helps me lose weight very well but there is a problem.

most of the time when im working if i feel a little hungry i cant concentrate very well. and its like a nerve attack that i have to eat something. something with sugar or carbohydrate in it.

as i have lots of activities in my job it doesnt let me have body activity. sometimes i walk for an hour but it cant be always.

can you give me suggestions that help me to be in good shape and have no problem with my job activities.

thank you for helping

Comment: This is off-topic for the site, as it's not really about exercise. General advice, don't take in too much sugar. A little bit can help when you're feeling uninspired, but too much and you're dealing with the crash. Try to eat lightly to avoid logyness. Caffeine, surprisingly enough, is not your friend unless you're doing monotonous work like database entry. The way it works on the brain actually blunts creative activity. Chair exercises and occasionally getting up and pumping out a few pushups or dips is probably your best best. Do it when you're feeling frustrated or your code is compiling.

Comment: thank you @SeanDuggan for your comment and suggestions. diet is most popular tag in this website. why you say its off-topic

Comment: Scope drift as much as anything else. We used to handle more diet questions, when starting out, to build up volume, but now, the site is getting much more specialized.
http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/523/policy-on-diet-questions

Comment: @virtouso - Nutrition is off topic unless it is part of an exercise regimen, and relates directly to that. There is nothing about working out in your posting.

Comment: @JohnP i wrote  about walking. and topic name is about fitness(being fit) excersice or diet. many thing can help for healthy body. dont make it hard.

Comment: @virtouso - SImply saying "Oh yeah, I walk occasionally" doesn't constitute an exercise regimen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should give a keto diet a try, I used to eat low carb a while ago while losing weight and I felt like even if I got hungry, I didn't get worn out mentally like you often do.

Could be that your blood glucose levels don't fluctuate as wildly on a keto diet, but that's entirely speculative.

Give it a week, the first days you'll feel like you can't focus at all, but you'll feel normal again in day 3-5.

Comment: thank you for you answer. im now reading about it. its ketogenic. right?

Comment: You're welcome, yes, ketogenic / LCHF.

Comment: i think i had to accept your post when saw diet worked but its long time but i found nothing exact bout sugar or what you call glocuse about it. what about natral sweet like date and what about chocolate and.. are they forbidden like carbs?

Comment: Honestly, what I'm reading from the answer is "concentrating is hard for the first few days of the diet, but returns to normal after that". Does that really address the question of "what diet should I pursue to maintain mental activity"?

Comment: virtouso, carbs of any type is out/should be limited severly, to make sure your body starts producing glucose and ketone bodies from fat, both dates and chocolate contains large amounts of carbs. It's a very strict diet, but worth trying out I think. Basically it's meat, fish and low-carb vegetables/fruits as well as fatty sauces. Sean Duggan, ok normal wasn't the right term, what I meant was that after the first few days, you feel good again, and when I had adapted to this diet, I didn't wear out mentally like I do on carbs.